# padding lists inside 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, keras

I have a 2D numpy array containing lists of tokenized words. I want to pad those lists with keras.processing.sequence-pad_sequences.

my 2d array's first dimension corresponds to dates. For every date, I have 25 (2nd dimension) lists of tokenized words (I want to pad these lists).

sample of my array:

```
>>>tokenized_news_seq_trunc[0]

array([list([915, 3691, 53, 48, 3692, 361, 579, 2432, 20]),
       list([453, 2433, 309, 1094, 133, 3, 228, 2433, 133, 3, 145, 133, 113]),
       list([2434, 3693, 251, 10, 16, 3694, 1731, 3695, 229, 1353, 580]),
       ..., list([865, 913, 555, 17, 8086]),
       list([3057, 1237, 121, 8087, 811, 2233, 497, 8088, 1, 8089, 8090, 44, 199, 8, 1771, 1072, 8091, 24, 72, 1280]),
       list([8092, 10, 16, 63, 151, 76, 622, 980, 1758, 3690, 174, 207, 840, 3279, 8093, 8094, 8095, 12, 1650, 735, 8096])],
      dtype=object)
```

I have tried:

```
for i in range(tokenized_news_seq_trunc.shape[0]):
    for j in range(tokenized_news_seq_trunc.shape[1]):
        #print(tokenized_news_seq_trunc[i][j])
        tokenized_news_seq_trunc[i[j]=pad_sequences(tokenized_news_seq_trunc[i][j], maxlen=MAX_LEN)
```

but I get an error: ValueError: `sequences` must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: 915.

We can see that it tries to iterate over every element of the list and it doesn't work.

I have also tried:

```
for i in range(tokenized_news_seq_trunc.shape[0]):
        #print(tokenized_news_seq_trunc[i][j])
    tokenized_news_seq_trunc[i]=pad_sequences(tokenized_news_seq_trunc[i], maxlen=MAX_LEN)
```

but it returns:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1989,27) into shape (1989)

(1989 is the number of dates, 27 is MAX_LEN)

Thanks for your help!

PS: Alternatively, I have a list of lists of lists containing my tokenized words, if there is a better way to do it with lists

Comment: Why bother with arrays at all when you have lists?

Comment: I didn't find any way to pad the 3rd dimension of my list of lists of lists. any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to pad nested sequences from the pypi anago documentation, but it does not truncate my sentences to MAX_WORDS (27). I have added the last if statement to implement truncating if sentences are too long

```
This function transforms a list of list sequences
into a 3D Numpy array of shape `(num_samples, max_sent_len, max_word_len)`.
Args:
    sequences: List of lists of lists.
    dtype: Type of the output sequences.
# Returns
    x: Numpy array.
```

```
def pad_nested_sequences(sequences, dtype='int32'):
    max_sent_len = 25
    max_word_len = 27
    for sent in sequences:
        max_sent_len = max(len(sent), max_sent_len)
        for word in sent:
            max_word_len = max(len(word), max_word_len)

    x = np.zeros((len(sequences), max_sent_len, max_word_len)).astype(dtype)
    for i, sent in enumerate(sequences):
        for j, word in enumerate(sent):
            if j<max_word_len:
                x[i, j, :len(word)] = word

    return x
```